# No bottom margin inside overflow:auto element

Tags: css

Here is my test case : http://jsfiddle.net/bpw98/15/

I have a div with `overflow:auto`, and a div inside it with a margin and a border. The inner div doesn't have its bottom margin in IE8, while it's displayed properly in Webkit and Firefox.

Comment: Maybe my emulator is rubbish, but it looks the same in IE7 to me. I also checked IE9's IE7 mode.

Comment: The bottom margin is displayed in IE7 for you? It seems strange. BTW, I'm using IE8, not IE7, I edited my question.

Comment: Ah, ok - yeah it does not show in IE8. Did you say IE7 first or was I hallucinating?

Comment: I said IE7, then I edited my question. But IE8 in compat mode does show the bottom margin, you are right... I'm baffled.

Comment: Check this:  http://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/MSIE8Bugs/MarginBottomChildNotRendered.html

Comment: It turns out that the problem is not with the absolute positioning, but with the overflow. So I rewrote my question.

Answer (score 1):

Opera renders it in a wrong way too:

The solution is in that browser: use padding in the outside box instead of using margin on the inside.

[Here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/bpw98/11/)

Unfortunately , it does not resolve the IE8 problem, I know. But it's a  known bug , CSS 2.1 spec does not cover precisely how this testcase should be rendered.

[Check this](http://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/MSIE8Bugs/MarginBottomChildNotRendered.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have a horrible hack for you:

```
div.outer:after {
    content:"";
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

This works for me but leaves a larger than `5px` margin at the bottom of `div.outer`:

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wwTnS/**

To get past this you could target IE8 only (so not IE8 and below as IE7 works correctly for once) and set `margin-bottom` to about `1px`...but then that is getting even more hacky. The code I have added above should not have any noticeable effect on any other browsers.

**Extra Note**

If you remove the `background-color` and check the code in IE9's IE8 compatability mode then it renders fine and the `margin-bottom` is `5px`. However, in my emulator (which is usually quite accurate), the `margin-bottom` is back to `0` if you do not add `background-color`.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by tildy, the problem is already documented. I think I found a working solution, but it requires extra markup: I added a div between outer and inner, with a 5px transparent border. See http://jsfiddle.net/bpw98/19/.

I tried to add padding to outer instead, but it didn't work either. The rationale between that is: "the scrollbar lets the user scroll content, and only content". So the scrollbar stops where content stops, even if there's padding or margin after that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of margin on `div.inner` maybe you could try setting `padding: 5px` on `div.outer`

Comment: It works in some browsers, but it doesn't work in IE8. As I have written previously.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically jsfiddle doesn't seem to work in IE8, which is quite funny.

Anyway, I had the same problem just now and went down the route of using :after on the inner element to inject content where the bottom margin should be:

```
div.inner {
    margin: 5px 5px 0;
}
div.inner:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
}
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bpw98/41/

However, this only works if you don't need that red border. I'm not sure if it was there just for the purpose of showing the issue or you actually need it? If it is needed, I'm afraid this answer won't work.

Answer (score -1):

I removed the height of the `.outer` div and it worked for me !
Propably it doesn't work because your inner div is higher than 100px;

Comment: Thanks, but I need the height (or a bottom: declaration on the outer div).